# HQL Fetch Join without knowing object implementation

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, mapping, hql

I'm having performance issues and I'm trying to add some fetch join to get some data in only one request.

My problem is :
I got a mapped object `AbstractObject`.
And I also got other mapped object like `ObjectA`, `ObjectB` etc... all are extending `AbstractObject`.

In my `ObjectA` I got a list of `foos`.
In my `ObjectB` I got a list of `otherFoos`.

What I'm trying to do :
I want to write a request like this :

`entityManager.createQuery("SELECT ao FROM AbstractObject ao LEFT JOIN FETCH ao.foos LEFT JOIN FETCH ao.otherFoos WHERE ao.id = ?1", AbstractObject.class)`

Problem: I got a `nullPointerException` because, I think, hibernate does not know `foos` or `otherFoos` for `AbstractObject`.
In my point of view, I do not know if I will have a `ObjectA` or `ObjectB`.

Do someone know a solution for this issue ?

Hibernate version : 5.0.12.Final

Comment: Additional information: I do not want use easter solution to always get foos and otherFoos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in order to execute an HQL query and return properties of multiple entities on the same result, you need a projection to a DTO.

So you will create a DTO for example ObjectAB, which will not be mapped, it will probably extending both Object A and B and then you will create your query and set a result transformer to this DTO.

Alternatively you could use a Tuple instead of a DTO, but this doesn't change the main idea. For more details of this methodology you may read [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: Thank you Christos ! That's exactly this kind of solution that I was searching for.